Why does my curry "bounce back" after stirring?
I recently cooked a big pot of curry, consisting largely of coconut milk, a bit of chicken stock and some vegetables. You can probably imagine that it was somewhat thick in consistency. The cooking process was such that in the beginning, I boiled coconut milk and then thawed the chicken stock in it. After all the stock had thawed, I stirred the mixture and noticed that after I stopped stirring, it kept rotating for a short while as expected, but then rotated into the other direction ever so slightly. It was not an optical illusion; I confirmed this by looking away while stirring and only looking back at the pot in the last moment.
My theory is that viscous stresses built up from the friction between the fluid and the walls of the pot, the relaxation of which caused the rotation in the opposite direction. This theory is supported by the fact that I did not observe a similar effect in water, a less viscous fluid. I know nothing of fluid dynamics, so does this make sense? What is actually going on?

When you stir a viscous fluid like the coconut milk-based curry, the fluid's rotational motion creates shear stresses within the fluid – caused by the friction between adjacent layers of the fluid moving at different velocities. The shear stresses are highest near the pot's walls due to the no-slip condition, where the fluid layer in contact with the stationary wall has zero velocity.
As you continue stirring, these shear stresses build up, and when you stop stirring, the fluid's momentum initially causes it to continue rotating in the same direction as your stirring. However, the built-up shear stresses start to relax, and this relaxation process can cause a temporary reversal of the flow direction.
The reversal occurs because the fluid layers near the walls of the pot, which were initially subjected to the highest shear stresses, start to decelerate and even reverse their direction due to the relaxation of these stresses. This momentum transfer from the outer layers to the inner layers can cause the entire fluid body to briefly rotate in the opposite direction before eventually coming to rest.
Your observation of this effect not happening with water, a less viscous fluid, is consistent with the fact that the reversal of flow is more pronounced in highly viscous fluids. In less viscous fluids, the shear stresses are not as significant, and the momentum dissipation occurs more uniformly throughout the fluid, making the reversal less noticeable or non-existent.

The best answer I can give you is friction. the friction of the curry against the sides of the pot while it is being stirred results in a spiral pattern on the surface, as the outside of the curry, due to friction, moves slower than the middle of the curry. However, the bottom of the pot has a different amount of friction on the curry than the air above it. Thus, the top of the curry can move more easily that the bottom. When you removed the spoon, momentum kept the curry spinning in the same direction you had been stirring it. Once there is no longer the force of the spoon upon the curry though, the bottom of the pot begins to flow more slowly than the top due to the greater friction. Likewise, the bottom of the curry is also the first of the pot to stop spinning, even whilst the top continues to rotate. Once the top slows to a stop the fluid is at an angle in a circle around the pot. The most relaxed state of it is however, straight up and down. Either the top of the curry has to move back, the bottom to move forward, or both to move halfway to attain a vertical direction. since there is more friction on the bottom, the top reverses to accommodate this, resulting in a backward motion on the surface. I would also agree with what you said about the sides, basically the same thing just with the greater friction being along the edges than in the middle rather than top and bottom. It might be a mix of these two causing the reverse. Hope this helps!
